# C# -> Android (Xamarin) -> start task every 5 minutes in Background

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, alarmmanager

i want to run a task every 5 minutes. i've tried to solve it with an IntentService and AlarmManager, my code:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

    var tkrServiceIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(GpsDataHandler));
    var tkrServicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetService(this, 0, tkrServiceIntent, 0);

    long interval = 5000;
    var firstStart = (DateTime.Now.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond) + 1000;

    var am = (AlarmManager)GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);

    am.SetInexactRepeating(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, firstStart, interval, tkrServicePendingIntent);

    Toast.MakeText(this, "Service started", ToastLength.Long).Show();
}
```

i receive the toast, that the service is started, but if i look in running services, there is no service for my application. Can you tell me where the problem ist?

Comment: Did you check whether you are receiving the toast when the app is in background or after getting killed.

Comment: @Hari_krish4 how can i test it?

Comment: If your service is running, Your toast message will get displayed at the bottom of your device.

Comment: @Hari_krish4 the toast message appears immediately after starting the application.

Answer (score 1):

IntentService in an "activity" (if we can call it) runing in Background of the app, so finnally it will call the `OnDestroy()` .. 
You can use the timer to fix your problem , like :

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

class TimerExampleState {
    public int counter = 0;
    public Timer tmr;
}

class App {
   public static void Main() {
    TimerExampleState s = new TimerExampleState();

    // Create the delegate that invokes methods for the timer.
    TimerCallback timerDelegate = new TimerCallback(CheckStatus);

    // Create a timer that waits one second, then invokes every second.
    Timer timer = new Timer(timerDelegate, s, 1000, 1000);

    // Keep a handle to the timer, so it can be disposed.
    s.tmr = timer;

    // The main thread does nothing until the timer is disposed.
    while (s.tmr != null)
        Thread.Sleep(0);
    Console.WriteLine("Timer example done.");
   }
   // The following method is called by the timer's delegate.

   static void CheckStatus(Object state) {
    TimerExampleState s = (TimerExampleState) state;
    s.counter++;
          Console.WriteLine("{0} Checking Status {1}.",DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay, s.counter);
        if (s.counter == 5) {
        // Shorten the period. Wait 10 seconds to restart the timer.
        (s.tmr).Change(10000,100);
        Console.WriteLine("changed...");
    }
        if (s.counter == 10) {
        Console.WriteLine("disposing of timer...");
        s.tmr.Dispose();
        s.tmr = null;
    }
   }
}
```

Source : https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Threading.Timer/

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code helps you:-

```
async void StartTimer()
{
   await Task.Delay(60000); //60 seconds
   // Do your code
   StartTimer(); // Again Call 
}
```

Call "StartTimer()" method where you want to. Call only once time then it calls automatically after 60 seconds.

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

you can create your own timer using xamarin forms device class

sample timer class:

```
public class Timer    {
        public Timer(int interval)
        {
            _interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(interval);
        }

        private bool _isRunning;
        private readonly TimeSpan _interval;

        private Action Tick;

        public void Start(Action tick)
        {
            _isRunning = true;
            Tick = tick;
            Xamarin.Forms.Device.StartTimer(_interval,() =>
            {
                Tick?.Invoke();
                return _isRunning;
            });
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            _isRunning = false;
            Tick = null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a service class. Call DoWork method in OnStartCommand method. Check whether the log is getting printed after every 5 seconds.

```
 public void DoWork()
            {
                var t = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    while (true)  
                    {
                       Log.Debug("Service", "Service running");    
                        Thread.Sleep(5000);
                    }
                });
                t.Start();
            }
```

Comment: Actually this (http://www.whatthedroid.de/2011/10/hintergrundprozesse-in-android-teil-1-started-services/) is exactly what i need, but in java. i have tried to translate it to c#.